# When i try to execute a command, i got a key error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im very new for programming and
I tried to make server specific prefixes with json by a youtube video. (for the guy who made it, its worked)
The bot started, but i got that error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sanbu\Desktop\Discord BOT\bot.py", line 11, in get_prefix
   return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
KeyError: '515616332268699649'
```

Here it is the code:

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix)
```

Comment: Yea so apprently `prefixes` doesn't contain the key `515616332268699649`. Check your JSON file. (Lets say you have the JSON `{"123" : true}`, but you're trying to fetch `5156..` which isn't there, only `123` is. That's the problem)

Comment: Have you tried not making the key a string? so use: `return prefixes[message.guild.id]`. It may also be worth using a `.get()` on prefixes with a default value, ``return prefixes.get(message.guild.id, None)`

Comment: What are the contents of `prefixes.json`?

Comment: I wanted to add contents to the json file when the bot joins a server.. but the bot was already on my server, so the file isn't updated.. this caused the error.
Also thank you for the fast helping :D